# how to get the table row id and all the text of that row

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to get the table row id and all text associated with the table id when the print button is clicked:
here is what i have so far:
JS:

```
newContent += Hesto.Html.StartTR(item.CommonCable, 'lineInfoRow');
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnprint" onclick="SelectedRow()">', null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.CommonCable, null, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Wire, null, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.WireLength * 1000, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.TerminalA, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.SealA, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.TerminalB, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.SealB, null);
            newContent = Hesto.Html.EndTR(newContent);
        });

        $('#AlternativeReworkCablesList').html(newContent);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="alternativeCableTable">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                                    <th>Print</th>
                    <th>Common Cable</th>
                    <th>Wire Type</th>
                    <th>Wire Length</th>
                    <th>Terminal A</th>
                    <th>Seal A</th>
                    <th>Terminal B</th>
                    <th>Seal B</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
                <tbody id="AlternativeReworkCablesList">
             </tbody>
             <tfoot>
             </tfoot>
        </table>
```

JS function:

```
function SelectedRow() {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr');
        var text = row.find('lineInfoRow').text();
        console.log(text);
}
```

and here is the image:
[image: table image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var tablid = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
  var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
```

also you have not passed object reference this in click call.it should be `onclick="SelectedRow(this)"`:

```
 newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnprint" onclick="SelectedRow(this)">', null);
```

Comment: i did change it but just an empty console.log is being outputed

Comment: @billah77: try logging id too.

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: here is what i have now function SelectedRow() {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
       console.log(rowtext);       
}

Comment: @billah77: can you share the fiddle.

Comment: this is an example i found i changed some variable and it does work here just that i don't know why it doesn't work on my application http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/22/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52523/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-billah77)